# How to combine two sets of lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two sets of lists with similar data which I need to combine into a dictionary. The list must contain both sets of information filling in wherever the other has a "-". So far this is what I have..

```
aList = [['Last Name', 'First Name', '2000', '2012'], 
       ['Roberts', 'Gloria', '-', '123000'], 
       ['Arreguin', 'Jeffrey', '81000', '-'], 
       ['Myers', 'George', '-', '86000'], 
       ['Willis', 'Mabel', '112000', '-'], 
       ['Oneal', 'Kevin', '96000', '77000'], 
       ['Paz', 'Barbara', '-', '77000'], 
       ['Franklin', 'Claude', '94000', '-'], 
       ['Bradley', 'Shannon', '89000', '-'], 
       ['Fix', 'Anna', '76000', '126000'], 
       ['Meyer', 'Loretta', '-', '116000'], 
       ['Daniels', 'Christina', '85000', '-'], 
       ['Graham', 'Veronica', '-', '136000']]

newList = [['Last Name', 'First Name', '2000', '2012'], 
       ['Meyer', 'Loretta', '123000', '-'], 
       ['Arreguin', 'Jeffrey', '81000', '-'], 
       ['Mielke', 'George', '137000', '-'], 
       ['Thomas', 'Lewis', '132000', '-'], 
       ['Harper', 'Crystal', '80000', '-'], 
       ['Young', 'Gary', '-', '94000'], 
       ['Franklin', 'Claude', '94000', '-'], 
       ['Hedrick', 'James', '-', '105000'], 
       ['Bradley', 'Shannon', '89000', '-'], 
       ['Thigpen', 'Michael', '79000', '-'], 
       ['Willis', 'Mabel', '112000', '-'], 
       ['Hullinger', 'Molly', '70000', '-'], 
       ['Myers', 'George', '-', '86000'], 
       ['Paz', 'Barbara', '-', '77000'], 
       ['Edwards', 'Kathryn', '117000', '97000'], 
       ['Roberts', 'Gloria', '-', '123000'], 
       ['Daniels', 'Christina', '-', '137000'], 
       ['Graham', 'Veronica', '-', '136000']]

def mergeData(newList,aList):
    aDict={}
    for item in range(1,len(newList)):
        key=(newList[item][0],newList[item][1])
        value=(newList[item][2],newList[item][3])
        aDict[key]=value

    for item in range(1,len(aList)):
        #stuck here not sure if im going right way with this 


print(aDict)
```

Here's a sample

```
newList= ['Meyer', 'Loretta', '123000', '-']
aList=['Meyer', 'Loretta', '-', '116000']
```

so the combined dictionary should be

```
{(‘Meyer’, ‘Loretta’): (‘123000’,’116000’)}
```

for this entry.

Comment: and my dictionary doesnt include the first item in both lists

Comment: Your range starts at 1, not 0; python lists use 0-based indexing.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters I just commented on why above

Comment: Can you show us exactly what output you're expecting? (Also, it might help to use a smaller sample set of input data, to cut down on the horizontal scrollbar action, and to make it easier to interpret.)

Comment: OK, that helps. So what's supposed to happen for someone like Jeffrey Arreguin, where both lists have a left value (and neither has a right value, but that seems less problematic)? Can we assume that if it appears in both, it must be the same, or we can pick either one arbitrarily, or something like that?

Comment: the two lists are similar data except that one may have more entries than the other

Comment: @abarnert if same value in both any of the two numbers will do for the dictionary, so basically yeah as you said must be the same

Comment: @BAI: OK, great question now that you've edited it (+1 from me). But in the future, you need to explain exactly what you're trying to do, or give sample output, or—best of all—both, because "combine two list into a dictionary" is too vague to turn into code.

Comment: @FernandoFreitasAlves: If you read the question, that won't actually do the right thing. It's pretty clear that the key is the first two values, not all 4 values. You could use a set as a first step, then write a merge operation that finds all elements with the same first two, but I don't think that would be any easier than writing the merge directly on the lists, as Martijn Pieters did.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the first list to build a dictionary with a dict comprehension:

```
aDict = {(e[0], e[1]): (e[2], e[3]) for e in aList[1:]}
```

Next loop over the other, with a helper function to pick one or the other based on the `-` values:

```
def pick(vals):
    return vals[1] if vals[0] == '-' else vals[0]

for e in newList:
    key = (e[0], e[1])
    existing = aDict.get(key, ('-', '-'))
    value = (e[2], e[3])
    aDict[key] = tuple(map(pick, zip(existing, value)))
```

For your first input that results in:

```
{('Arreguin', 'Jeffrey'): ('81000', '-'),
 ('Bradley', 'Shannon'): ('89000', '-'),
 ('Daniels', 'Christina'): ('85000', '137000'),
 ('Edwards', 'Kathryn'): ('117000', '97000'),
 ('Fix', 'Anna'): ('76000', '126000'),
 ('Franklin', 'Claude'): ('94000', '-'),
 ('Graham', 'Veronica'): ('-', '136000'),
 ('Harper', 'Crystal'): ('80000', '-'),
 ('Hedrick', 'James'): ('-', '105000'),
 ('Hullinger', 'Molly'): ('70000', '-'),
 ('Last Name', 'First Name'): ('2000', '2012'),
 ('Meyer', 'Loretta'): ('123000', '116000'),
 ('Mielke', 'George'): ('137000', '-'),
 ('Myers', 'George'): ('-', '86000'),
 ('Oneal', 'Kevin'): ('96000', '77000'),
 ('Paz', 'Barbara'): ('-', '77000'),
 ('Roberts', 'Gloria'): ('-', '123000'),
 ('Thigpen', 'Michael'): ('79000', '-'),
 ('Thomas', 'Lewis'): ('132000', '-'),
 ('Willis', 'Mabel'): ('112000', '-'),
 ('Young', 'Gary'): ('-', '94000')}
```

All put together again in your merge function:

```
def pick(vals):
    return vals[1] if vals[0] == '-' else vals[0]

def mergeData(newList, aList):
    aDict = {(e[0], e[1]): (e[2], e[3]) for e in aList[1:]}

    for e in newList:
        key = (e[0], e[1])
        existing = aDict.get(key, ('-', '-'))
        value = (e[2], e[3])
        aDict[key] = tuple(map(pick, zip(existing, value)))

    return aDict
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what he wants (I don't really understand the question), but if it is, surely that should be `aList[1:] + newList[1:]` (or `chain(islice(aList, 1, None), islice(newList, 1, None)`.

Comment: Anyway, the reason I don't think this is what he wants is that he's got keys (like `'Arreguin', 'Jeffrey'`) that appear in both lists, and that bit about 'both sets of information filling in whereever the other has a "-"', which… must mean _something_.

Comment: I got to the same conclusion, so I am expanding it now.

Comment: I can guess what it's supposed to do for Christina Daniels: `('85000', '137000')`. But what about Jeffrey Arreguin? Is it just the `('81000', '-')` that appears in both lists?

Comment: @abarnert yes if both contain - for an entry then just leave the hyphen

Comment: Wow, I wrote up almost the exact same thing, except that I had different names for `vals` and `existing`, and no parens around the `key` assignment.

Comment: @MartijinPieters one question is that for loop in the helper function or out

Comment: @BAI: The `for` loop is outside of the helper function.

Comment: @MartijinPieters so it would fall under my merge function

Comment: @BAI: You can put the helper function inside or outside your merge function, but the loop would be inside.